# Set alpha blackout to all pages in ViewPager except current

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Need set blackout (alpha = 0.5f) to all pages except current in `ViewPager`.

In this `ViewPager` I show fragments.
[image]

Comment: I would do an interface and make the fragments implement this interface, then I would add a pageChangeListener on the View Pager and every time it is called, fire the method of my interface (something like setTransparency(boolean isTransparent)). Sorry not that much time for a well described answer but I can do it if you really need it.

Comment: @LaurentMeyer thanks man

Comment: I like the question/ proposed solution very much. So I'm a little afraid the comment might get deleted some time in the future, and  I really would like to upvote all parties involved in making this complete. As soon as anyone has got the time, of course :)